# I need help to pass uiSearchBar in NavigationBar title Swift

Tags: ios, swift3

All topics on this seem a little old and did't help me with bringing this searchBar over the navigationBar. [This is what I get with my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgBpd.png)
[Debug view hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pio6O.png).

This is my navigationBar code

```
func setNavigationBar() {
 UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black

 let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
 let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: 50))
 let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "search")

 UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.white]
 UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white

 let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.stop, target: nil, action: #selector(backAction))
 let myBtn: UIButton = UIButton()
 myBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "quiticon"), for: .normal)
 myBtn.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:70, height:70)
 myBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backAction), for: .touchUpInside)

 self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(UIBarButtonItem(customView: myBtn), animated: true)

 navItem.leftBarButtonItem = doneItem
 navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)
 //self.view.addSubview(navBar)
 self.tableView.addSubview(navBar)
 }
```

Tableview

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureClubs()
    setNavigationBar()

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 0, 0, 0)
    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)

    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar

    let searchBar = self.searchController.searchBar
    searchBar.delegate = self

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = self.searchController.searchBar
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    //self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

    self.resultsController.tableView.delegate = self
    self.resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self
    definesPresentationContext = true
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your navigation bar transparent?

Comment: `UISearchBar` and its `UISearchController` are notorious for weird frame resizing having "a mind of their own". A container view could help, try my solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43278771/5329717

Comment: I don't know I thought just having a navigationBar and putting the UISearchbar in the title view would work