# iOS Search bar mess up with Navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I am facing issue with UISearchBar & UISearchDisplayController. When I click on searcher then it messes up with the Navigation bar. I have tried to fix with many codes but did not work. I am creating UIsearch bar and UISearchDisplayController via pragmatically. Please help. Any suggestion will be Great.

```
 // Search Bar
searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,subView.frame.size.width, 52)] ;
searchBar.delegate=self;

//UISearchDisplayController
searchController=[[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self] ;
[searchController setDelegate:self];
[searchController setSearchResultsDataSource:self];
[searchController setSearchResultsDelegate:self];
[searchController.searchResultsTableView setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Try my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43278771/5329717

Comment: @Kamil.S , I tried but bad luck on this did not work.

Comment: Can you share your code in a demo project?

Comment: Finally, I have fixed above search bar issue. I just removed UISearchDisplayController and just add UISearchBar and implemented its delegate methods for handling searching in current View Controller. Worked like a charm, Party time soon.

Comment: @Ravi please post your solution as an answer

Comment: @Kamil.S

I just remove UISearchDisplayController and add UISearchBar and implemented its delegate methods

UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,subView.frame.size.width, 52)] ;
[self.view addSubview:searchBar];